# How to dynamically add Material-UI icons in React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a menu with icons, kept in an array of objects, where the icon tagnames are stored in strings as they are present in Material UI:

```
interface MenuButton {
    text: string,
    onClickFunction: Function
    icon: string
}

export default function Catalog() {    
    ...
    const generalButtons: MenuButton[] = [
        {
            text: "New Client",
            onClickFunction: addNewClient,
            icon: "InfoIcon"
        },
        {
            text: "New Product",
            onClickFunction: addNewProduct,
            icon: "AddShoppingCartIcon"
        },
        {
            text: "New Gift",
            onClickFunction: addNewGift,
            icon: "CardGiftcardIcon"
        }
    ]
    ...
```

Then where I would use them in a List setting. This is only the simplest of the possible failing solutions I tried, will show the issue.

```
return (
    ...
    <List>
        {generalButtons.map((button, index) => {
            const CustomIcon = button.icon
            return (
            <ListItem key={button.text} disablePadding>
                <ListItemButton onClick={(e) => button.onClickFunction(e)}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <CustomIcon />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={button.text} />
                </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
         )
     })}
    </List>
)
```

The icons did not appear, instead I got this kind of errors:

```
Warning: <InfoIcon /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For material icons, to use them dynamically, you will need to do an import like this, which I think you are.

```
import { SelectedIcon, ... } from '@mui/icons-material';

Map<string,ReactComponent> menuIconToComponentMap = new Map<string,ReactComponent>();

map.put("SelectedIcon", SelectedIcon);

export const menuIconToComponentMap = menuIconToComponentMap;
```

This imports all icons into your bundle, which is not a huge deal but impacts performance long term. You can whitelist certain icons by importing them one by one into your own map.

Then you should be able to access them like this

```js
  const MenuIcon = menuIconToComponentMap.get(button.icon);
  ....

   <MenuIcon/>
  ....
```

Comment: This throws another error: 
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("...@mui/icons-material/index")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("...@mui/icons-material/index")'.ts(7053)

Comment: If you don't want //ts-ignore it, the best way to get around that type error is to create your own file called "MenuIconMap.ts" that is  essentially  a map of the `Map<string,ReactComponent>`. It really is the best for long term bundling. Icon sets are huge

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but it still won't do. I can to a separate ts file like this: 
`import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';

const menuIconToComponentMap: Map<string, ReactElement> = new Map();

menuIconToComponentMap.set("MailIcon", MailIcon);`

This last line with the icon itself is in error: 
Argument of type 'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.ts(2345)

Comment: The easiest thing to do with typescript errors like that is to take the type referenced and insert it in as the type. Just copy and paste. Problem solved :)

Comment: Awesome tip with that. Yet another issue when I try to use the created MenuIcon in the template: `JSX element type 'MenuIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: Can you drop a debug point in the app when you get it out of the map and inspect what you are getting out? I wonder if it's the raw SVG and you need to wrap it in <SVGIcon/>

Comment: Strange... it works mate, ts still gives the error, yet it works regardless.