# How to fix: JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have an ongoing question here [How to dynamically create custom elements in React TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76549060/how-to-dynamically-create-custom-elements-in-react-typescript/76549123#76549123) and it has a flaw still.

```
const generalButtons: MenuButton[] = [
    {
        text: "New Client",
        onClickFunction: addNewClient,
        icon: "InfoIcon"
    },
    {
        text: "New Product",
        onClickFunction: addNewClient,
        icon: "AddShoppingCartIcon"
    },
    {
        text: "New Gift",
        onClickFunction: addNewClient,
        icon: "CardGiftcardIcon"
    }
]
```

In a separate file I have a map with the icons themselves:

```
import InfoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Info';
...
import { OverridableComponent } from '@mui/material/OverridableComponent';
import { SvgIconTypeMap } from '@mui/material';

const menuIconToComponentMap: Map<string, OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }> = new Map();

menuIconToComponentMap.set("InfoIcon", InfoIcon);
...

export default menuIconToComponentMap;
```

Here is the use and the error:

```
<List>
    {generalButtons.map((button, index) => {
        const MenuIcon = menuIconToComponentMap.get(button.icon)
        return (
            <ListItem key={button.text} disablePadding>
                <ListItemButton onClick={(e) => button.onClickFunction(e)}>
                    <ListItemIcon>

                        <MenuIcon />

                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={button.text} />
                </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
        )
    })}
</List>
```

Error  is: JSX element type 'MenuIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures. How do I make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the error "JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const generalButtons: MenuButton[] = [
    {
        text: "New Client",
        onClickFunction: (e) => addNewClient(e),
        icon: "InfoIcon"
    },
    {
        text: "New Product",
        onClickFunction: (e) => addNewClient(e),
        icon: "AddShoppingCartIcon"
    },
    {
        text: "New Gift",
        onClickFunction: (e) => addNewClient(e),
        icon: "CardGiftcardIcon"
    }
]
```

```
<List>
    {generalButtons.map((button, index) => {
        const MenuIcon = menuIconToComponentMap.get(button.icon)
        return (
            <ListItem key={button.text} disablePadding>
                <ListItemButton onClick={button.onClickFunction}>
                    <ListItemIcon>

                        <MenuIcon />

                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={button.text} />
                </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
        )
    })}
</List>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. It didn't seem to help on the MenuIcon error, and it seems to added a new problem with the function calls. That is not the issue, that works as is. My issue is only with the <MenuIcon /> giving the TS error.